# STM32 pulled up GPIO pins work stange after being connected to the ground

Tags: stm32, gpio, pullup, stm32f10x, stm32f103c8t6

I use stm32_smart v2 development board and try make a cheap and reliable 7 bit input interface using 7 jumpers from GPIO to the ground. Internal pull up resistors are used. The first time I did not connect any GPIO to the ground and had 3.3V on them.

After the first connection I have from 1V to 2.7V on used GPIO, even when they are not connected to the ground any more. I have no idea what is going on, but it felt like I burned something.

I'm uploading all the code even unused functions, to make sure all I provide all the info.

[image: My schematic]

```
#include "stm32f10x.h"
//#include "stm32_eval.h"
#include "stm32f10x_gpio.h"
#include "stm32f10x_rcc.h"
#include "stm32f10x_usart.h"
#include "stm32f10x_exti.h"
#include "stm32f10x_tim.h"
#include "stdio.h"
//#include "tm1637.h"
#include "misc.h" /* High level functions for NVIC and SysTick (add-on to CMSIS functions) */


#define TRUE 1
#define FALSE 0
#define NoONE 0
#define TEAM_A 1
#define TEAM_B 2

//Timer ISR sets this flag to communicate with the main program.
static __IO uint8_t TimerEventFlag;   
static __IO uint8_t TimerTicks=0;   
static __IO uint8_t ControlTeam=NoONE;
static __IO unsigned int TeamATime;
static __IO unsigned int TeamBTime;
static __IO unsigned int InitialTime=65;

unsigned int timeformat(unsigned int seconds){
    unsigned int min=0;
    unsigned int sec=0;
    min=(seconds/60);
    sec=seconds%60;
    return min*100+sec;
}

void Configure_DIP(void){
    GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct;
        /* Set pin as input */
    GPIO_InitStruct.GPIO_Mode = GPIO_Mode_IPU;
    GPIO_InitStruct.GPIO_Pin = GPIO_Pin_10|GPIO_Pin_9|GPIO_Pin_8;
    GPIO_InitStruct.GPIO_Speed = GPIO_Speed_2MHz;
    GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStruct);

    GPIO_InitStruct.GPIO_Mode = GPIO_Mode_IPU;
    GPIO_InitStruct.GPIO_Pin = GPIO_Pin_12|GPIO_Pin_13|GPIO_Pin_14|GPIO_Pin_15;
    GPIO_InitStruct.GPIO_Speed = GPIO_Speed_2MHz;
    GPIO_Init(GPIOB, &GPIO_InitStruct);
}
/* Configure pins to be interrupts */
void Configure_AButton(void) {
    /* Set variables used */
    GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct;
    EXTI_InitTypeDef EXTI_InitStruct;
    NVIC_InitTypeDef NVIC_InitStruct;

    /* Enable clock for GPIOA */
    RCC_APB2PeriphClockCmd(RCC_APB2Periph_GPIOA, ENABLE);

    /* Set pin as input */
    GPIO_InitStruct.GPIO_Mode = GPIO_Mode_IPU;
    GPIO_InitStruct.GPIO_Pin = GPIO_Pin_0;
    GPIO_InitStruct.GPIO_Speed = GPIO_Speed_2MHz;
    GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStruct);

    /* Add IRQ vector to NVIC */
    /* PA0 is connected to EXTI_Line0, which has EXTI0_IRQn vector */
    NVIC_InitStruct.NVIC_IRQChannel = EXTI0_IRQn;
    /* Set priority */
    NVIC_InitStruct.NVIC_IRQChannelPreemptionPriority = 0x00;
    /* Set sub priority */
    NVIC_InitStruct.NVIC_IRQChannelSubPriority = 0x00;
    /* Enable interrupt */
    NVIC_InitStruct.NVIC_IRQChannelCmd = ENABLE;
    /* Add to NVIC */
    NVIC_Init(&NVIC_InitStruct);

    /* Tell system that you will use PA0 for EXTI_Line0 */
    GPIO_EXTILineConfig(GPIO_PortSourceGPIOA, GPIO_PinSource0);

    /* PA0 is connected to EXTI_Line0 */
    EXTI_InitStruct.EXTI_Line = EXTI_Line0;
    /* Enable interrupt */
    EXTI_InitStruct.EXTI_LineCmd = ENABLE;
    /* Interrupt mode */
    EXTI_InitStruct.EXTI_Mode = EXTI_Mode_Interrupt;
    /* Triggers on rising and falling edge */
    EXTI_InitStruct.EXTI_Trigger = EXTI_Trigger_Falling;
    /* Add to EXTI */
    EXTI_Init(&EXTI_InitStruct);
}

/* Configure pins to be interrupts */
void Configure_BButton(void) {
    /* Set variables used */
    GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct;
    EXTI_InitTypeDef EXTI_InitStruct;
    NVIC_InitTypeDef NVIC_InitStruct;

    /* Enable clock for GPIOC */
    RCC_APB2PeriphClockCmd(RCC_APB2Periph_GPIOA, ENABLE);

    /* Set pin as input */
    GPIO_InitStruct.GPIO_Mode = GPIO_Mode_IPU;
    GPIO_InitStruct.GPIO_Pin = GPIO_Pin_5;
    GPIO_InitStruct.GPIO_Speed = GPIO_Speed_2MHz;
    GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStruct);


    NVIC_InitStruct.NVIC_IRQChannel = EXTI9_5_IRQn;
    NVIC_InitStruct.NVIC_IRQChannelPreemptionPriority = 0x00;
    NVIC_InitStruct.NVIC_IRQChannelSubPriority = 0x00;
    NVIC_InitStruct.NVIC_IRQChannelCmd = ENABLE;
    NVIC_Init(&NVIC_InitStruct);

    GPIO_EXTILineConfig(GPIO_PortSourceGPIOA, GPIO_PinSource5);

    EXTI_InitStruct.EXTI_Line = EXTI_Line5;
    EXTI_InitStruct.EXTI_LineCmd = ENABLE;
    EXTI_InitStruct.EXTI_Mode = EXTI_Mode_Interrupt;
    EXTI_InitStruct.EXTI_Trigger = EXTI_Trigger_Falling;
    EXTI_Init(&EXTI_InitStruct);

}

int main(void)
{
  //Holds the structure for the GPIO pin initialization:
  GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStructure;  

  uint16_t bitwise_time=0;    //for value from the DIP switches.
  uint16_t portA_vals;
  uint16_t portB_vals;
  uint16_t iden16=1;


    //Configure_AButton();
    //Configure_BButton();
    Configure_DIP();


//init game settings
    portA_vals=~GPIO_ReadInputData(GPIOA);
    portB_vals=~GPIO_ReadInputData(GPIOB);
    //bit operations
    if(portA_vals&iden16<<10){ 
        bitwise_time=bitwise_time|1<<0;}
    if(portA_vals&iden16<<9){ 
        bitwise_time=bitwise_time|1<<1;}
    if(portA_vals&iden16<<8){ 
        bitwise_time=bitwise_time|1<<2;}
    if(portB_vals&iden16<<15){ 
        bitwise_time=bitwise_time|1<<3;}
    if(portB_vals&iden16<<14){ 
        bitwise_time=bitwise_time|1<<4;}
    if(portB_vals&iden16<<13){ 
        bitwise_time=bitwise_time|1<<5;}
    if(portB_vals&iden16<<12){ 
        bitwise_time=bitwise_time|1<<6;}
//set that as teams times
    if(bitwise_time==0){
        InitialTime=30;
    }else if(bitwise_time==127){
        InitialTime=99*60;
    }else{
        InitialTime=bitwise_time*60;
    }
    TeamATime=InitialTime;
    TeamBTime=InitialTime;

  // Configure SysTick Timer
  /*System timer tick is used to measure time. 
    The Cortex-M3 core used in the STM32 processors has a dedicated timer 
    for this function. Its frequency is set as a fraction of the constant
    SystemCoreClock (defined in file system_stm32f10x.c in the 
    STM32F10x Standard Peripheral Library directory.) 
    We configure it for 1 msec interrupts*/
    if (SysTick_Config(SystemCoreClock/10))  while (1); //If it does not work, stop here for debugging.
//loop
  while (1) {
    asm("nop"); //doing nothing. should put into some energy save mode
  }//End while(1)

} //END main()


// Systic interrupt handler
//Every 100 msec, the timer triggers a call to the SysTick_Handler. 
void SysTick_Handler (void){
    TimerTicks++;

}

/* Set interrupt handlers */
/* Handle AButton interrupt */
void EXTI0_IRQHandler(void) {
    /* Make sure that interrupt flag is set */
    if (EXTI_GetITStatus(EXTI_Line0) != RESET) {
        /* Do your stuff when PA0 is changed */
        ControlTeam=TEAM_A;
        /* Clear interrupt flag */
        EXTI_ClearITPendingBit(EXTI_Line0);
    }
}

/* Handle BButton interrupt */
void EXTI9_5_IRQHandler(void) {
    /* Make sure that interrupt flag is set */
    if (EXTI_GetITStatus(EXTI_Line5) != RESET) {
        asm("nop");
        if(GPIO_ReadInputDataBit(GPIOA, GPIO_Pin_5)==0){ 
            ControlTeam=TEAM_B;
        }
        /* Clear interrupt flag */
        EXTI_ClearITPendingBit(EXTI_Line5);
    }
}


#ifdef USE_FULL_ASSERT
  void assert_failed ( uint8_t* file, uint32_t line)
  {
    /* Infinite loop */
    /* Use GDB to find out why we're here */
    while (1);
  }
#endif
```

Comment: "Internal pull up resistors are used ... I have from 1V to 2.7V on used GPIO even when they are not connected to the ground anymore." When you have internal pullups, you should expect there to be voltage on ungrounded inputs, right? What do you think should be happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're doing is very dangerous (for your chip). If the pin is configured as input, all should be fine. But when the pin is accidentally configured as output, setting the pin high causes a short-circuit to Gnd. The output stage of that port can potentially burn.

- Such accident can happen while you're developing your software. Perhaps you configure the pin as "output" instead of "input". And poof -> chip damaged...
- <strike>At chip startup, most pins are for a brief moment in an "undefined" state.</strike> Note: this is incorrect. For more info, see comments below from people who corrected me.

I recommend to make the connection like this:

[image]

The 1k resistor protects the pin of your chip.

**Note:** The damage inside your chip can be tricky to recognize. If you're "lucky", your chip fails entirely. You toss it away and start with a new one. More painful is a chip that fails partly. Most of it keeps working, so you believe that the chip is okay. You focus on the software, trying to find the bug. It doesn't come to your mind that the hardware is damaged. Plenty of frustration...

Comment: Thank you! I just realized that at the first moments during chip initialization pins can be in uncertain state (at least for me) but some of them are already grounded.

Comment: Hi @user54041 , you're welcome. I'm happy my answer helped you. Yes indeed, pins are generally in an uncertain state at startup. That's why you need this protection :-)

Comment: @K.Mulier this not the truth. They are 100% of time in 100% defined HI-Z state .

Comment: @P__J__ during startup, I thought some pins are "undefined" for a brief moment. Are you sure this isn't the case, and it's safe to connect them to Gnd without a protective resistor? If you are absolutely sure about this, I can make a change in my answer ^_^

Comment: Resistors aren't a bad idea, but damage from an output being shorted to ground is rare.  And the idea that outputs on this family would be briefly active as outputs at boot is pure fantasy.  The pins do what the data sheet says they do, otherwise people wouldn't be able to build products around them.  Any pins that would be active are documented as such, for example if you boot with the hardware strapping such that a serial bootloader is entered.  But that is unlikely to involve the pins depicted.

Comment: Hi @ChrisStratton and P__J__ , Thank you for pointing out my mistake. I have adapted my answer accordingly ^_^